# Retrofit 2 add support for custom / other request methods (HTTP verbs)

Tags: android, rest, httprequest, retrofit, retrofit2

In Retrofit 2 I am able to use annotations in services to define what HTTP method needs to be used. For example:

```
public interface UserService {

    @GET("users")
    Call<UsersResponse> getAllUsers(@Header("access-token") String token)

    @POST("user")
    Call<UserResponse> postUser(@Header("access-token") String token, @Body User user)

}
```

I find this very convenient, but I'm missing some HTTP request methods (verbs) like LINK and UNLINK. Is it possible to somehow extend Retrofit to create support for extra methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible using the HTTP-annotation:

```
public interface AccountService {

    @HTTP(method = "LINK", path = "users",  hasBody = true)
    Call<BaseResponse> linkUsers(@Header("access-token") String token, @Body LinkUsersRequest linkUsersRequest);

}
```

You can also use the HTTP-annotation to create a DELETE request with a request body

Comment: Hello Bart,
 my code is not working it always says Custom method AUTH, must not have a Body

@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
        @HTTP(method = "AUTH",  path = "login/{deviceId}", hasBody = true)
        Call<Success> getLogin(
                @Path("deviceId") int deviceId,
                @Body RequestBody password);

I am using retrofit 2.X